Eclipse IDE crash on Ubuntu 24.04
While executing a program on eclipse ide it's crash multiple times. I have configured with JDK 21 & latest eclipse verion. I'm unable to run any program on it. Please help me out if any know about this.Thanks in advance.

 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x000076e11bd7d190, pid=26583, tid=26584
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (21.0.3+9) (build 21.0.3+9-Ubuntu-1ubuntu1)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (21.0.3+9-Ubuntu-1ubuntu1, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libwebkit2gtk-4.1.so.0+0xd7d190]
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport -p%p -s%s -c%c -d%d -P%P -u%u -g%g -- %E" (or dumping to /home/santosh/core.26583)
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-21
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.


Have you made sure it is the right version of Java for that version of Ubuntu?

Yes. it's default version

Might be this crash: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78355080/2670892
